# APFS partition on an external drive stopped working

Tags: macos, time-machine, disk-utility, partition, apfs

I have an external drive formatted in APFS. I use it to store some media files and it contains a Time Machine sparse bundle which is encrypted. I can chose to mount or not the sparse bundle. Today I was planning to make a backup with Time Machine. But in order to do that I have to mount first the hard drive.

That's it for the intro. The problem I have now is that MacOS can't mount partitions inside this drive anymore. I tried everything with fcsk and diskutil with no success so far.
Error is the following:

```
> Exécution de fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/rdisk3s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Samsung was formatted by diskmanagementd (945.200.129) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.101.1).
Checking the object map.
error: btn: invalid key order (0) oid 2325271 / oxid 0 / level 0 / flags 0x6
    previous key: e8 b1 01 00 00 00 00 00 b9 d4 00 00 00 00 00 00
    current key:  ee ad 01 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
    next key:     ef ad 01 00 00 00 00 00 b3 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
Object map is invalid.
The volume /dev/rdisk3s1 could not be verified completely.
Le code de sortie de la vérification du système de fichiers est 8.
Rétablissement de l’état original : démonté.
La vérification ou la réparation du système de fichiers a échoué. : (-69845)
```

I am able to add new partition inside this drive but not being able to mount the legacy partition.

I run the apfs-inspect tool and here is the output:  https://pastebin.com/wnBHK37g

There seems to be something with the OID 0x402 in `nx_omap_btree` but I have no clue what does that mean.
Would you mind helping me finding a way to fix that?

Thanks,
Roma

Comment: I believe the B-tree implementation in my `apfs-inspect` tool has some bugs which are causing it to not find the volume superblock, since `fsck_apfs` seems to be finding it just fine. As such, my tool will be no good until that is fixed, and your `nx_omap_btree` is fine. As for the actual error that `fsck_apfs` is reporting (`btn: invalid key order` in volume object map), I cannot see why it thinks that there is an invalid key order; the three keys that it shows are in order. If you are able to chat sometime, I may be able to help you use the `apfs-explore-*` commands to examine the situation.

Comment: Thanks Jivan to pop up. We can chat on Twitter if you don't mind. I've just added you.